# Is there a way to open a window only once using angular services?

Tags: angular, authentication, service, refresh, polling

I have an Angular login service that do a lot of stuff.. and it basically refresh users credentials every X minutes.
If something went wrong refreshing credentials, it opens a new AWS windows, and a new library will poll and endpoint that will return "true" if you clicked "Allow" on that windows.
Basically, as it is an angular service, it will be executed for every tab, resulting in two new AWS windows if you have 2 tabs open, and so on.

Is there a way to execute it only once?

I'm opening a new windows with `window.open(url)`. But i don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to give a name to your window, it should be re-used if already opened :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/open

> If a window with the name already exists, then url is loaded into the
> existing window. In this case the return value of the method is the
> existing window and windowFeatures is ignored.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: Well, one of the key concept of stackoverflow is to provide info about your code, so that people can try to figure out what's wrong. Can you show some code where you actually open these windows ?

Comment: I'm using `window.open(URL, name)` ... you can check on chrome console that if I ran this, it would work as you would expect, (if a window is already opened in this tab with that name, it will load the URL into the existing windows). But if you run the same line on another tab, it will open a new tab, even if the mentioned tab is open. What I need is a way to only open a new window if no other tab has opened it. IDK if its possible.

Comment: From my experience, people did develop Chrome extensions for such a purpose, but it wasn't versy stable and reliable ... sorry.